# Separating Hadoop Map and Reduce tasks

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, reduce

In a 3 node hadoop cluster. I would like the master to be 1 node. Map task taking place in one node and reduce tasks in 1 node. Map and reduce tasks should be separated. Is it possible? As far as i noticed both run together. It will be great if you can shed some light. Thank you !

-Sethu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is everything else than optimal because the map output must ALWAYS be copied to another server. 
But you can simply modify your mapred-site.xml on the servers.

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
    <value>4</value>
    <description>The maximum number of map tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker.</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
    <value>4</value>
    <description>The maximum number of reduce tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker.</description>
</property>
```

On the server where no reducers should run you put into the reduce.task.maximum a zero. And vice versa for the other servers.

Comment: Hi , Should i mention the maximum no of map tasks always? Is it enough if i jus specify <property>
    <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
    <value>0</value>
    <description>The maximum number of reduce tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker.</description>
</property> , in the node where only map tasks should run and vice versa in node where only reduce should run ?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what the default is (it might be the number of cores) so just provide these two values. Try it out.

Comment: Do you mean the default number of map/reduce tasks may be based on the number of processors in that system?

Comment: I don't know, why don't you try yourself?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works great. Regarding the default value . I have to dig in more. Will get back once I find that :)

Comment: This is the site level configuration. How to set up the number of map tasks for a specific Job?